# An alternative to BSTS method with non bayesian method

Tags: bayesian, causality, frequentist, bsts

If I have to select an alternative way for causally finding the impact of a treatment using frequentist methods for a time series data, Bayesian Structural Time Series is one of them but is there a non-bayesian way to get around this? Additionally are there any python or r packages that let me do this?